# laravel terminable middleware, pass parameters from controller

Tags: laravel, middleware

I want to use a terminable middleware for request logging:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Session\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Helpers\Logger;

class LogRequest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        Logger::log($request, $response, $additionalInfo)
    }
}
```

How can I pass the **$additionalInfo** from the controller to the middleware?

EDIT: 
Unfortunately the additional info is generated in the controller. I therefore cannot hard code it in the route middleware function

Comment: I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to add to **kernel.php**:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
         ......
        'LogRequest'=> \App\Http\Middleware\LogRequest::class
    ];
```

in the **LogRequestMiddleware:**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $additionalInfo)
        {   
            //here you have $additionalInfo
            $request->attributes->add(["info" => $additionalInfo]);
            return $next($request);
        }
   public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
       dd( $request->attributes);
    }
```

And in controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
       $additionalInfo = "test"
       $this->middleware("LogRequest:$additionalInfo");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work since I need the parameter in the terminate method and not the handle method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set some attribute to the request object in your controller while handling it, and the request object itself will be passed to terminate($request, $response) as the first parameter. Then you can extract whatever you set in your controller and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: You might be able to do this

**Controller**

```
$request->attributes->add(['additionalInfo' => 'additionalInfoValue']);
```

**Middleware**

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    $additionalInfo = $request->attributes('additionalInfo' => $additionalInfo);
    Logger::log($request, $response, $additionalInfo)
}
```

Comment: he would pass middleware from controller not from routing

Comment: Unfortunately the additional info is generated in the controller. I therefore cannot hard code it in the route middleware function